# does this implication relation induced by a subset of the power set have a name?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, order-theory

Let $S$ be a nonempty set and $F\subseteq\mathcal{P}(S)$. Define $x\Rightarrow_F\!y$ if and only if $$\{A\in F:x\in A\}\subseteq\{A\in F:y\in A\}$$ and $x\!\!\iff_{\!\!\!\!F}\,y$ if and only if $x\Rightarrow_F\!y$ and $y\Rightarrow_F\!x$. Does the partial order $\leq_F$ on the quotient $S\big/\lower1pt\hbox{$\!\!\iff_{\!\!\!\!F}$}$ defined by **x** $\leq_F$ **y** if and only if $x\Rightarrow_F\!y$ for some $x\in$ **x** and $y\in$ **y** have a name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this map has a name, but let $q:S\to\mathcal{P}(F)$ be defined by $q(x)=\{A\in F:x\in A\}$.  This induces a **preorder** on $S$ via $x\le y\iff q(x)\subseteq q(y)$.  Preorder means $x\le x$ and $x\le y\land y\le z\rightarrow x\le z$.  Like any preorder this induces an equivalence relation on $S$ via $x\sim y\iff q(x)=q(y)$.  This equivalence relation is used in combinatorics of infinite sets.  For instance, in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9308220.pdf) paper it is used in Theorem 3 when $F$ is indexed by an ordinal.  After some polishing the map can be used to prove Kuratowski's theorem that any injection $\mathbb{N}\to\mathcal{P}(S)$ yields a surjection $S\to \mathbb{N}$ as explained [here](https://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/dedekind-infinite-power-sets).  I don't know what you need this for, but the induced equivalence relation is not a stranger.

Comment: Thank you for seeing what my flawed question was trying to ask about---this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The relation $\Rightarrow_F$ which you claim is a partial order, isn't a partial order. Here's a counterexample.

Let $S$ be $\{0, 1, 2\}$ and let $F$ be $\{\{2\}\}$. Now let $x$ and $y$ be $0$ and $1$ respectively.
The following is true:

$$\{A\in F:x\in A\} = \{A\in \{\{2\}\}:0\in A\} = \varnothing$$
$$\{A\in F:y\in A\} = \{A\in \{\{2\}\}:1\in A\} = \varnothing$$

Therefore $x\Rightarrow_F y$ and $y\Rightarrow_F x$, but $x$ and $y$ are not the same.

Comment: Or, a simpler counterexample, have $S$ with at least two elements and consider $F=\{\varnothing\}$ or $\{S\}$.

Comment: For sure. Thanks, Asaf.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need for a covering condition.  I don't know if it makes the implication a partial order but it was the next thing to try.  I need that relation to be a partial order.

Comment: @mathematrucker Asaf already provided a counterexample where $\cup F = S$.

Comment: @GitGud thanks let me figure out what I'm trying to ask.  The specific example that motivates the question is a set $S$ of equations (i.e., unordered pairs) and family of subsets of $S$. My goal is to obtain a comprehensive list of ``equation $\implies$ equation'' based on the family.

Comment: I took one last shot at fixing this by putting the order on a quotient of $S$ instead of on $S$.  It makes the question seem even sillier than it already was, because there's surely no such term for this ordering, but I think it's at least a well-defined question now.